# I cannot access to second page on Docker .net core

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a web application developed with .Net core Entity Framework. There is a login page, and after the login page it redirects to /Home/Index. Everything is going OK while on localhost when I run "dotnet run"

I deployed the application to DigitalOcean with Docker. It deployed successfully and I can access to the application via browser. However, after I try to login from /Home/Login, it redirects to /Home/Index but it returns 404.

My Dockerfile, which is deployed and built successfully.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /surveyprocessor

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln ./
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build app
COPY . ./
#WORKDIR /surveyprocessor
RUN dotnet publish -c release -o output --no-restore

# final stage/image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /surveyprocessor
COPY --from=build /surveyprocessor/output .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Anket.dll"]
```

So, my HomeController.cs:

```
        {
            var userName = HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserName");

            if (userName==null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
            }

            var list = (from a in _context.Records select a).ToList();

            ViewBag.errorList = TempData["errorList"];

            if (ViewBag.errorList != null)
            {
                List<string> errorList = new List<string>();
                foreach (var item in ViewBag.errorList)
                {
                    errorList.Add(item);
                }
                ViewBag.errorList = errorList;
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.errorList = null;
                ViewBag.Successful = Convert.ToBoolean(TempData["Successful"]);
            }
            return View(list);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult>Create(
            [Bind(
            "FirstName", "LastName", "PhoneNumber", "CustomerCompany"
            )]
            Records records)
        {
            List<string> errorList = new List<string>();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                    records.RecordedUser = HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserName");
                    _context.Add(records);
                    //_context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("exec dbo.sil");
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    TempData["Successful"] = Convert.ToBoolean(true);
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
                else
                {
                errorList.AddRange(ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors).Select(e => e.ErrorMessage).ToList());
                TempData["Successful"] = Convert.ToBoolean(false);
            }
            TempData["errorList"] = errorList.ToList();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            var userName = HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserName");

            if (userName != null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Login([Bind(
            "Username", "Password"
            )] string userName, string Password)
        {
            UserHelper userHelper = new UserHelper();

            string WindowsUsername = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

            bool user = userHelper.GetUser(userName,Password);

            if (user==false)
            {
                return BadRequest("Giriş Başarısız!");
            }

            SetSession(userName, Password);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

Startup.cs:

```
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<TestContext>(parameter => parameter.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetSection("MySettings").GetSection("DbString").Value));
            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddSession(options=> {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToInt32(Configuration.GetSection("MySettings").GetSection("DefaultTimeOut").Value));
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            });
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            }
                );
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Login}");
            });
        }
    }
```

launchSettings.json:

```
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:47126",
      "sslPort": 44373
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Anket": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:7002"
    }
  }
}
```

Should I be providing more files?

The application link: https://github.com/sahancava/SurveyProcessor

Comment: A shot in the dark: Do you need `[HttpGet]` on the Index method in HomeController?

Comment: Just tried after your reccomendation. No positive result.

Comment: It still returns me 404 on /Home/Index despite I don't face 404 on the same page while on localhost.